# Ideal pressure cooker size for cooking a pound (454g) of beans

Tags: beans, pressure-cooker

I'm shopping for a pressure cooker. Could anyone advise me on what size of pressure cooker is sufficient for cooking a pound of beans? I don't want to buy one that is too small and overcrowd it.

Answer (score 2):

A pound of beans should be 4-5 cups (about 1L) when cooked. I think it's pretty hard to find pressure cookers smaller than 4 quarts (16 cups or 3.8L), so you shouldn't have any worries at all. Even the smallest one you can find will have plenty of extra space.